# $f $ is differentiable on $(0, 1)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f^{'}(x)=\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$. Show $f^{'}(0) = \alpha$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Suppose that $f $ is differentiable on $(0, 1)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f^{'}(x)=\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f^{'}(0)$ exists and $f^{'}(0) = \alpha$.

How should I approach this problem. I need some hints. Second thing, are we trying to prove here that $f^{'}$ is continuous at $0$. We know $f$ is not differentiable at $0$ because $f$ is not even defined in the neighbourhood of $0$.

What is the intuition behind this question? I just do not want to solve it, I want to see the background process.

Comment: Hint: A theorem by Darboux states that the derivative of a function cannot have jump discontinuities.

Comment: @uniquesolution That means by the theorem you have mentioned, if a function is defined and continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$, then $f^{'}$ is continuous on end points.

Comment: Your formulation of the problem is not optimal. Do you consider the function $f(x)=|x|$ to satisfy the assumptions of your question? If not, then you must provide information about what is going on on the left side of zero too.

Comment: @uniquesolution I think the OP is talking about the right hand derivative at $0$ which exists for your function. His assertion is correct but the proof is a little involved. I know one place where enough hints are given: Real and Abstract Analysis by Hewitt and Stromberg.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  Can I use  the Mean value theorem here, for every $x > 0$, by the MVT, there exists $b_{x} \in (0, x)$ such that $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=f^{'}(b_{x}).$   Now by definition $$f^{'}(0)=lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(f(x)-f(0)}{x}=lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(b_{x})=lim_{b_{x}\rightarrow 0}f(b_{x})=\alpha$$       Is this correct?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Somehow I am not able to edit last comment. It is $f^{'}$ instead of $f$ in the last two steps.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - If the question is only about one-sided continuity, then a one-sided version of Darboux's theorem suffices.

Comment: @MathamanTopologius You are right. I was making things too complicated. MVT gives the answer easily.